# Changes in environment object only notifying subscirbers once

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I have an app where I use firebase firestore and snapshot listeners. I use an Observable Object class where I observe a state. This state notifies subscribing views in order for me to remove the snapshotListeners on that instance. I inject it into my view hierarchy and use it in certain views. I also have a signOut method where I allow users to sign out which changes the didLogOut property below.

This is the manager i'm observing

```
class StatusManager: ObservableObject{

@Published var didLogOut: Bool = false

}
```

This is where I log users out

```
                Button(action: {
                
                isLoggedIn = false
                lastLoggedEmail = ""
                lastLoggedUserPassword = ""
                lastLoggedUserType = ""
                
                statusManager.didLogOut = true

                try? Auth.auth().signOut()
                
                navStack.pop(to: .root)
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Sign Out")
                    .font(Font.custom("Roboto-Light", size: 14))
                
            })
```

The issue is, when i sign out, it works the first time. The subscribed views are notified about the changes, which removes the snapshot listeners, and the user signs out via the Auth.auth().signOut() method. However, Once i get back to the login screen from signing out, If i sign in a second time, and try to logout, the views aren't notified about the change in didLogOut. This causes my app to crash because the user signs out via firebase but the listeners are still active. The listener isn't able to access that data because the user isn't signed in. Resulting in this

```
Listen for query at adminData/melsaville5@gmail.com/drivers failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Comment: When do you set `didLogOut` back to `true`?

Comment: Man am i an idiot ‍♂️. Thank you @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to reset didLogOut to false when the user logs back in.